# Prove that $\lim_n (-n+\sin(n) )= -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Prove that $\lim_n (-n+\sin(n)) = -\infty$

So I need to show that if $B'$ is any number, then there is a number N' such that 
$$n>N' \implies S_n\lt B'$$

I am having trouble feeling confident in my proof so please tell me if my method is right, if my answer is correct, and if there is a more precise way to use the definition I provided to prove this infinite limit.

Poof:
Let $B'$ be an arbitrary negative number then let $N'=\max\{\dfrac{\pi}{2},-B'\}.$

Then let $S_n = -n +\sin(n)\lt B'$
since n>N' then $S_n = -n + \sin(n)\lt -N'+\sin(N') \lt -N' + 1\lt -N' = -(-B')=B'$

Thus $S_n \lt B'$

Therefore $S_n \rightarrow -\infty$

Let me know how this looks.

Comment: Looks good. But the part with $-N'+1<-N'$ does  not work. I would just define $N'$ as $-B'+1$

Comment: So have N' = max{$\frac{\pi}{2}, -B'+1$} Then my final steps would results as follows:

$-N' +1 = -(-B'+1)+1 =  B'-1+1 = B'$

Comment: @B ry Yes. And the $\max\{\frac{\pi}{2},\cdot \}$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right general idea, but you’re making it too complicated, and some of what you’ve written is simply wrong: $-N'+1$ is *greater than* $-N'$, for instance.

The key is to notice that $\sin n\le 1$ for all $n$, so $S_n=-n+\sin n\le-n+1$ for all $n$. Given your $B'$, you want to choose $N'$ so that $S_n<B'$ whenever $n>N'$, i.e., so that $-n+1<B'$ whenever $n>N'$. Now $-n+1<B'$ if and only if $-n<B'+1$, which in turn is true if and only if $n>-B'-1$. Thus, if you take $N'=\lceil-B'-1\rceil$, $n>N'$ will ensure that $n>-B'-1$ and hence that $S_n<B'$.

Here $\lceil x\rceil$ is the *ceiling* of $x$, the smallest integer $m$ such that $x\le m$.

Note that there’s no need to restrict $B'$ to negative reals, though it does no harm to do so, and there’s no reason to introduce $\frac{\pi}2$ (which in any case wouldn’t give you an integer for $N'$.

Comment: okay I appreciate the input and advice, thank You!

Comment: @Bry: You’re welcome!